# How to position a custom Tab Bar exactly as a normal Tab Bar with it's official height and with .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom) for all the iPhone?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, tabbar

I created a Custom Tab Bar and it works perfecly. The only problem that i have is i cannot find how to find the correct position, height for it depending of the iPhone model.

How can i do that?

My code (The Custom Tab Bar is in the HStack) :

```
struct Home: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewRouter = ViewRouter()
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.259467423, green: 0.5342320204, blue: 0.7349982858, alpha: 1))
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                if self.viewRouter.currentView == "HomeList" {
                    HomeList()
                } else if self.viewRouter.currentView == "Messages" {
                    Messages()
                }else if self.viewRouter.currentView == "Favorites" {
                    Favorites()
                }else if self.viewRouter.currentView == "Search" {
                    Search()
                }else if self.viewRouter.currentView == "Profiles" {
                    Profiles()
                }

                HStack{
                    HomeTabItem(viewRouter: self.viewRouter, tabImage: "house", tabText: "HomeTitle", viewName: "HomeList", badgeNumber: 0)
                    HomeTabItem(viewRouter: self.viewRouter, tabImage: "envelope", tabText: "MessagesTitle", viewName: "Messages", badgeNumber: 69)
                    HomeTabItem(viewRouter: self.viewRouter, tabImage: "star", tabText: "FavoritesTitle", viewName: "Favorites", badgeNumber: 0)
                    HomeTabItem(viewRouter: self.viewRouter, tabImage: "magnifyingglass", tabText: "SearchTitle", viewName: "Search", badgeNumber: 0)
                    HomeTabItem(viewRouter: self.viewRouter, tabImage: "person", tabText: "ProfileTitle", viewName: "Profiles", badgeNumber: 0)
                }.frame(width: self.screenSize.width, height: 58)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.259467423, green: 0.5342320204, blue: 0.7349982858, alpha: 1)))

            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a GeometryReader to find the bottom safe area (geometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom) and then add that to the height of the tab bar that you want.

Comment: Nice! That's part of the answer! 

Works perfectly for positioning, i used it in padding instead of adding to the height.

Now how can i get the exact Height of the Tab Bar depending of the iPhone model?

New code :

`
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {geo in
            ...

                HStack{...}
.frame(width: self.screenSize.width, height: 58)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(.bottom, geo.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
                .background(...)
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)

`

Comment: You can probably get the tab bar's height through the UIKit tab bar. Maybe create a variable below screenSize that is tabBarHeight and set it equal to UITabBarController().tabBar.frame.height

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code and a special thanks to nicksarno who was the genius behind this!  ;-)

```
struct Home: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewRouter = ViewRouter()
    var tabBarHeight = UITabBarController().tabBar.frame.height
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {geo in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                if self.viewRouter.currentView == "HomeList" {
                    HomeList()
                } else if self.viewRouter.currentView == "Messages" {
                    Messages()
                }else if self.viewRouter.currentView == "Favorites" {
                    Favorites()
                }else if self.viewRouter.currentView == "Search" {
                    Search()
                }else if self.viewRouter.currentView == "Profiles" {
                    Profiles()
                }
                
                HStack{
                    HomeTabItem(viewRouter: self.viewRouter, tabImage: "house", tabText: "HomeTitle", viewName: "HomeList", badgeNumber: 0)
                    HomeTabItem(viewRouter: self.viewRouter, tabImage: "envelope", tabText: "MessagesTitle", viewName: "Messages", badgeNumber: 69)
                    HomeTabItem(viewRouter: self.viewRouter, tabImage: "star", tabText: "FavoritesTitle", viewName: "Favorites", badgeNumber: 0)
                    HomeTabItem(viewRouter: self.viewRouter, tabImage: "magnifyingglass", tabText: "SearchTitle", viewName: "Search", badgeNumber: 0)
                    HomeTabItem(viewRouter: self.viewRouter, tabImage: "person", tabText: "ProfileTitle", viewName: "Profiles", badgeNumber: 0)
                }.frame(width: geo.size.width, height: tabBarHeight)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(.bottom, geo.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
                .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.259467423, green: 0.5342320204, blue: 0.7349982858, alpha: 1)))
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        }
    }
}
```